# How is versioning supposed to work with the new Typescript 2 @types?

Tags: typescript, package.json, typescript-typings

Instead of using typings, with Typescript 2 we're supposed to install dependencies in the @type namespace via npm. But the versioning seems to be a mess.

For example, if I do an `npm view urijs`, I see these versions:

```
 '1.17.1': '2016-02-25T10:06:35.269Z',
 '1.18.0': '2016-04-30T09:27:13.484Z',
 '1.18.1': '2016-05-29T16:43:29.257Z',
 '1.18.2': '2016-09-25T19:59:43.684Z',
 '1.18.3': '2016-11-17T22:13:15.243Z'
```

If I do an `npm view @types/urijs`, I get this:

```
 '1.15.24-alpha': '2016-07-04T01:27:50.730Z',
 '1.15.25-alpha': '2016-07-08T21:42:31.607Z',
 '1.15.26': '2016-07-14T16:18:54.580Z',
 '1.15.27': '2016-08-02T16:14:09.235Z',
 '1.15.28': '2016-08-19T15:45:23.543Z',
 '1.15.29': '2016-08-25T19:04:03.083Z',
 '1.15.30': '2016-09-19T18:17:20.887Z',
 '1.15.31': '2016-10-05T21:04:18.199Z'
```

Say I have a dependency on urijs@1.18.1, how am I supposed to know which @types version to get? Do I have to resort to looking at the dates and hoping I get a good one?

Is this just a case of the developer "doing it wrong"? Ie is the plan that developers release a matching @types version with the same number, preferably at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, for any major.minor.xxx.xxx version of an `@types` package should reflect the latest major.minor.xxx.xxx of the package itself. So if it were published, 1.18.49 on `@types` would ideally reflect `1.18.3` of the package itself.

It may just be the case that there've been no updates between version 1.15 and 1.18 that required an update to the `.d.ts` file. It may also just be someone "doing it wrong" like you said.

You should definitely feel free to update the `.d.ts` version on [the `types-2.0` branch on DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/types-2.0).